# Trying to open multiple instances of CMD at once in C#

Tags: c#

I'm making a C# program that runs multiple video files through ffmpeg in the command prompt at once, but even though I can't find a problem in the code only one instance will open at a time.

```
private void Render()
    {
        length = listBox1.Items.Count;
        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            ThreadStuff tws = new ThreadStuff(listBox1.Items[x].ToString(),x);
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(tws.ThreadProc));
            t.Start();
        }
public class ThreadStuff
{
    public ThreadStuff(string filename, int x)
    {
        Process cmd = new Process();
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("ffmpeg -i \"" + filename + "\" tmp" + x.ToString() + ".mp4");
        cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        cmd.StandardInput.Close();
        cmd.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "list.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine("file tmp" + x.ToString() + ".mp4");
        }
    }

    public void ThreadProc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` blocks execution. Why do you need it here?

Comment: Oops. Must have been left over from some debugging. I'm not smart sometimes

Comment: maybe offtopic. why do you want to execute cmd.exe that executes ffmpeg.exe ? better start a process that executes ffmpeg directly.

Comment: When I tried that it lead to ffmpeg closing upon open and not doing it's task and other strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() blocks execution. Why do you need it here? -  Aleksey L.

This was the problem